# Addition to values in a foreach-loop

Tags: php, loops

So I have an array.

```
$numbers1 = [31, 60, 54, 7, 13, 2, 9, 68, 5, 2, 9, 68, 5, 2];
```

What I have to do is use a foreach-loop to sum each item with 20 and then place them in a new Array, `$newArray`. This is what I've come up with so far.

```
$numbers1 = [31, 60, 54, 7, 13, 2, 9, 68, 5, 2, 9, 68, 5, 2];

foreach ($numbers1 as &$value) {
    $newArray = $value + 20;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, as I receive the answer 22 instead of the array with the sum of the numbers. I know I have to echo it out, but I have to do that later in the exercise. I appreciate the help.

Comment: You say _sum each item with 20_ but you add 17? And _But it doesn't seem to be working._ is not helpful.

Comment: If you have to put the new value in a new array, then why are you modifying the existing value?

Comment: Your code doesn't even contain `$newArray`, so how is anything supposed to end up in it?

Comment: Hint: `$arrayYouWantToAddSomethingTo[] = $thingYouWantToAdd;`

Comment: Sorry I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question basically works. Replace `$newArray` with `$value` as so:

```
$numbers1 = [31, 60, 54, 7, 13, 2, 9, 68, 5, 2, 9, 68, 5, 2];

foreach ($numbers1 as &$value) {
    $value += 20;
}
```

Then if you need it in a new array use add the following line afterwards:

```
$newArray = $numbers1;
```

Since you are passing `$value` by reference you can use the `$value += 20` line.

---

If you don't want the pointless array reassignment you can do the following:

```
$numbers1 = [31, 60, 54, 7, 13, 2, 9, 68, 5, 2, 9, 68, 5, 2];

foreach ($numbers1 as value) {
    $newArray[] = $value + 20;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

#### General solution, not suitable for this exact question

Use `array_map` instead(for better codestyle):

```
$newArray = array_map(function ($x) {
     return $x + 20;
}, [31, 60, 54, 7, 13, 2, 9, 68, 5, 2, 9, 68, 5, 2]);
```

This will assign the function to each entry and thus will increase each value by 20.

Comment: The OP _specifically_ said that she wanted to use a `foreach` loop: "What I have to do is use a _foreach-loop_"

Comment: Thank you for this, but yeah unfortunately I have to use a foreach loop.

Comment: Shall I leave it here for other users who do not need to obey to that? (to the other StackOverflow users)

Comment: I think you should, could be helpful to other people :)